# Writing legible sortkeys without tuple parameter unpacking in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose I have a collection `events` which contains tuples of length two that store some arbitrary information, for example a day and an event.

In Python 2 I can write the very readable

```
sortkey = lambda (day, event): some_function(day)
events_sorted = sorted(events, key=sortkey)
```

In Python 3, the first line will raise a `SyntaxError` because tuple parameter unpacking has been removed. I cannot use a two argument lambda-function as the key, so I have to resort to the far less readable

```
sortkey = lambda day_and_event: some_function(day_and_event[0])
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: well... what other sort of solution are you looking for? If you wanted to add any other logic to the `sortkey` function you'd have to adapt it to a function anyway.  Personally the syntax of lambda has always confused me, `lambda (day, event):` looks like it takes two arguments appose to one tuple.

Comment: Your solution is the one offered and in PEP 3113, afraid this is the only way (without moving it to the function as in Tadhg's approach).

Answer (score 1):

Use a two line function instead of a `lambda` expression:

```
def sortkey(day_and_event):
    day, event = day_and_event
    return some_function(day)
```

Comment: I was hoping there's a less verbose and still readable way, but I'm afraid not.

Comment: the only other thing that comes to mind is use a `namedtuple` and do `some_function(day_and_event.day)` but that would require a (possibly impossible) change to the `events` collection, sorry.